# How to use data.json in browsers local storage to load the page with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, local-storage

I have one function that manipulates data stored in data.json file: when some buttons are clicked data changes and then the function updates the UI each time, according to new data. So everything needed for loading the page is stored inside data.json. Now I want those changes to persist, so data.json doesn't restart and the page is loaded according to the last version of it. I upload the data at the end of the function like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("Data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

And the local storage file seems to track every change made on the page. But when I refresh the page, the changes disappear and the code loads from my local data.json file (which is again back to its beginning state). So, what I need is that data.json changes persist inside the local storage when I refresh the page and that the code loads from that local storage, not my local file. I'm loading data from my computer like this:

```
import data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

is there a similar way to load it from browsers local storage?

I have never saved anything inside browser local storage, and this is my first project trying to do this. I thought that storing everything inside one single json file, so that page loads according to that file was a good idea, because all I would need to save changes was to upload a copy of that file inside the browsers local storage and then somehow load it from there. But it seems more complicated than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import defaultData from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };

const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("Data");
const data = cachedData ? JSON.parse(cachedData) : defaultData;
```

That will read the data from local storage if it exists, else it will fall back on the json file.